# merge count number of topics, comments and last comment date forum sql

Tags: php, sql, join, group-by

Im developing a forum-like website
I want to put the next information within a div

```
 Category: Cars
 Topics: 27  Comments:5436
 Last Comment: 01.04.2020 //php formated
```

Here I count the number of posts

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM posts as p
   WHERE p.category= :category 

   $sql->execute();
```

Here I count the number of comments

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM comments as c
   LEFT JOIN posts as p ON c.id_post = p.id_post
   WHERE p.category= :category 

   $sql->execute();
```

Here I find the last comment date

```
   SELECT max(c.date) as maxdate
   FROM comments as c
   LEFT JOIN posts as p ON c.id_post = p.id_post
   WHERE p.category= :category 
   GROUP BY c.id_comment

   $sql->execute();
```

My greatest probles is How should I merge all those three sql sentences and 3 pdo execution in one single sql statement (single pdo execution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join and aggregate. Consider:

```
select 
    p.category,
    count(distinct p.id_posts) no_posts,
    count(c.id_post)           no_comments,
    max(c.date)                date_last_comment
from posts p
left join comments c on c.id_post = p.id_post
where p.category= :category 
group by p.category
```

Comment: wow. it works like a charm. this is a total different approach I ve already know!! has you maybe by chance a sql tutorial where I could  learn to make statements this way? thank you. +1